# How do I stub out a protected method in a object in scala

Tags: scala, stubbing

Example:

```
object Test {

  def test = {
    doTest
  }

  protected def doTest = {
  // do something
  }
}

class MockTest extends WordSpec with Mockito{
  "" in {
    val t = spy(Test)

    // how do i stub out doTest?
  }
}
```

I have a Test class with a protected doTest method. How do I stub out this protected method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise to make `doTest` package private, so that clients of your object won't be able to call it, but you'll be able to test it from within the same package.

```
package com.company.my.foo

object Test {

  def test = {
    doTest
  }

  private[foo] def doTest = {
  // do something
  }
}
```

and

```
package com.company.my.foo

class MockTest extends WordSpec with Mockito{
  "" in {
    val t = spy(Test)

    when(t.doTest()).thenReturn("foo")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Test` is a singleton (all Scala objects are), you can subclass a *class*, but not an *object*. Hence `protected` is a bit meaningless here - you're saying this method should only be accessible to subclasses, but it's not possible to have any (since `Test` is an object).

You have a couple options depending on what is best suited to your needs. 1) you can make `Test` a class and then extend it, or 2) change the access level of `doTest` to `public` [which is the default in Scala if you don't specify an access modifier]

Comment: Even though it doesn't hurt to make doTest public, I didn't create 'doTest' for other people to use--it's made specifically for my test method. I want to make it public, but I don't think 'making it public just so I can stub it' is a good enough reason